# How to pass a value from groovy to another testcase URL as parameter in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have to write a Groovy script which get some dynamic value for me from response

I need to pass this value to my request URL as a parameter in an another testcase/step

My first URL is as below from which I am getting response:-

```
https://mywebsite/api/Products
```

I am able to get this dynamic id by below groovy script:-

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

    responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("3_Level_product").getPropertyValue("response")
    slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
    log.info (slurperresponse.products.request_id)
```

I need to pass that value in below like URL:-

```
 https://mywebsite/api/get_response?request_id=0d8fe4d9
```

Comment: Can you confirm 1. Do you already have the (dynamic from previous response) value available in groovy script? If no, can you post the sample raw response and what value do you needed? 2. What is type of first test step (soap, rest, jdbc etc)? 3. Do you need to pass it to a test step of same test case or different test case?

Comment: Please update /edit the question and include the above details. That will help to answer better.

Comment: Thanks Rao for reply .. Yes, I am able to get the response using groovy script .. I am new for soap-ui so may be you can suggest  a better way

Comment: 2) It's a Rest API 3) Yes, I want to add it to the same step firstly but I am facing a issue. My response API have different URL as above and when ever I am changing the resource for the step then the soup-ui changing it for every step

Comment: I am bit confuse ri8 now .. do I missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Within the same Test Case**

Open your existing **Groovy Script** and add below lines to it. Follow the comment in the code snippet.

```groovy
//As you mentioned you have the value(extracted from _1st step_) in groovy script, 
//so assign value in place of "<replace your value here>" below variable
def valueFromPreviousResponse = <replace your value here>
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('REQUEST_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE', valueFromPreviousResponse)
```

Now go to the next test step, edit your endpoint

**from**
`https://mywebsite/get_response?request_id=0d8fe4d9-ed28-421f-8b90-b9b2afac4196`

**to**
`https://mywebsite/get_response?request_id=${#TestCase#REQUEST_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE}`

Then each time you run the test, *dynamic value* will be sent in the *2nd step*.
The will help you only *within the test case* as mentioned.

**Within the Test Suite**

If you want that value should be available to a test step which is in either same or different test case, follow below:

```groovy
//As you mentioned you have the value(extracted from _1st step_) in groovy script, 
//so assign value in place of "<replace your value here>" below variable
def valueFromPreviousResponse = <replace your value here>
context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('REQUEST_ID', valueFromPreviousResponse)
```

Now go to the next test step or any test step in *any test case* **within the test suite**, edit your endpoint

**from**
`https://mywebsite/get_response?request_id=0d8fe4d9-ed28-421f-8b90-b9b2afac4196`

**to**
`https://mywebsite/get_response?request_id=${#TestSuite#REQUEST_ID}`

Comment: Thanks for the brief discription Rao .. But the problem is my URL is different .. Can you please give me some steps.. I have also created a new question for same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786729/how-to-modify-the-resource-of-a-teststep-in-soap-ui-without-changing-for-other-s

Comment: without it I can't proceed with your above step.

Comment: my first URL contains /products and other contains /get_response

Comment: It may be that each step might have different url or `resource`, you just need the variable one to use property expansion like I mentioned in the response `${#TestCase#REQUEST_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE}` or `${#TestSuite#REQUEST_ID}` as per your need.

Comment: Did you try the solution given? what happened?

Comment: My third request is Get request while my first request was post... I am able to extract the request_id from first request and I also set the above code as per you provided .. But now My first request have /product at the end while my 2nd request have /get_response ... I am now not even able to edit my 2nd reuest to Get method and neither I am able to change the URL

Comment: see I have added a image also in my question. See the End point is different but the request sent is different .. some how that /api/product is still  appanding in URL which make my reuqest wrong.. another thing is I am not able to change the request to GET

Comment: I have resolve half of my issue by refering your answer.. I have accepted your answer..

Comment: The problem is if I am making my one step as Post then my other step is also converting into post while I need that as GET request..

Comment: you can post your answer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786729/soapui-why-if-i-am-changing-my-one-request-as-post-then-all-other-request-als