# If a request is changed to POST, then SoapUI changing all other requests into POST method

Tags: rest, soapui

A testcase contains 2 requests and 1 groovy script.

Now 1st request is using `POST` method and 2nd request is using `GET` method.

Now I am facing an issue that If I am changing the 2nd request as `GET`, my 1st request also gets turned into `GET` request while I need 1ST Request to remain as `POST`.

How to handle this situation?

I am new in `Soap UI`. any suggestion will be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shubham Jain, please go thru the documentation of soapui and it video available [here](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html) if you are confused.

Comment: Yes I know this problem. It is confusing. You need to create a new project for the other request.

Comment: Then How can I Add that in my teststep ?

Comment: Can I add other project request in my present project testcase?

Comment: Which version of SoapUI are you using? Did you follow the [link](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html) provided earlier, go thru it. Really sorry, can you make the problem little more clear? Each operation/method migh have different method (`GET`, `POST`) and parameters.

Comment: By the way, did you create a `Test Suite` and `Test Case`, then `Test Steps`? Also, you can go thru this [link](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html). All I can understand that there is something wrong in the way you are using and doubt if there is a problem in _soapUI_ tool.

Comment: I am using latest 5.2.1..

Comment: I have added a images which can show my structure .. Right now I have tried to create a new project for GET request and then try to use it in my teststeps .. but still it my request name as :- Chekcing_Request_Product_Import posting it as POST while in main project it is GET

Comment: Yes I have gone through the link ... May be I am missing something in it :(

Comment: One this is not clear that you mentioned 1st request is of `POST`, then again saying you are changing it to `POST`. Can you clarify ?

Comment: means it vice verca .. If i change 1st to anything then other change as same.. I have added a another image ..

Comment: I need 1st request as Post and 2nd request as Get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer my answer here:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786729/if-a-request-is-changed-to-post-then-soapui-changing-all-other-requests-into-po/34831359#34831359
```

there I have described a full example to achieve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple methods under the same endpoint - this is what REST is designed to do!

Under your "Api" resource, right-click, and select "New Method". Select this new one to be of type GET. This is going to be your "CheckingResponse". So the final hierarchy for your endpoint will look like:

```
REST Project 1
+-[REST] http://endpoint.URL/...
  +-Api [] <--- THIS IS A RESOURCE
    +-[POST] Api <--- THIS IS YOUR CURRENT METHOD
    | +-3LevelProducts
    +-[GET] Api <--- THIS IS A NEW METHOD
      +-CheckingResponse
```